# Create one stacked bar plot from one normalized dataframe column

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I'm struggling with creating a single stacked barplot from the dataframe below:

```
             sender_department
Sales                 0.441629
Operations            0.288440
Admin                 0.244021
IT                    0.013952
Engineering           0.007403
Marketing             0.004556
```

sender_department column is a normalized distribution of occurences of each index (created from original dataframe.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I finally came up with this idea:

```
df.transpose()

active_senders.plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do that?

[image]